# Is there a way to build rpm's and deb's on the same system

Tags: ubuntu, debian, redhat, rpm, package-management

I have a large Java enterprise application that is required to output rpm and deb packages.

Currently this means that we build the application on two different boxes, one with CentOS and the other with Ubuntu 10.04.

In an ideal world I'd be able to run the build on either of these to systems and produce rpm and deb packaging in a single pass.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm .

Comment: that looks just the thing

Comment: AFAIK fpm does not provide a way to provide a package repository for several clients. Related: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/issues/817

Answer (score 6):

See the [Open Build Service](http://www.open-build-service.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be building packages in a chroot environment, using something like [pbuilder](http://pbuilder.alioth.debian.org/) for debs and [mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock) for RPMs. Mock can be run on Ubuntu so you can do everything on a single build machine. Chroot build environments ensure that packages are built cleanly and aren't affected by any weirdness in the host machine. They also use the correct dependencies when building for different OS versions.

Comment: Not quite sure why a chroot environment is useful in this case. but if it lets me build both types of packages on a single disto I'll have a look

Comment: Answered in the answer.